# Javascript String parameter comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, parameters, undefined

I have also tried doing 'cv', and "cv" but still comes as undefined.

**HTML ( Laravel Blade)**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteType({{$cv->id,"cv"}})">
    Delete Current CV
</button>
```

**JS Function**

```
function deleteType(id, type) {

    const TypeParameter=type; //Undefined

    alert(TypeParameter);

    let messageType = '';

    let url = '';

    switch (TypeParameter) {
        case 'cv':
        url = 'deleteCV';
        messageType = 'cv'
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `{{$cv->id,"cv"}}`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius is in Laravel

Comment: And if you inspect the rendered HTML what does it reveal?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes? `"cv"` -> `'cv'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the put the word **CV** out of the `{{ }}`, like:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteType({{$cv->id}}, 'cv')">
    Delete Current CV
</button>
```